# How can i know that vector x is passing b/w vectors a, b, c, d?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been given 4 vectors a, b, c, d, and another vector x. How can i know that vector x is passing b/w vectors a, b, c, d? If the vectors were in R^2 then i will check only for 2 vectors. but they are in R^3 so minimum 3 vectors are required to check. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What in the world does this mean?

Comment: Are the vectors defined in $R^2$ or $R^3$?

Comment: @TedShifrin is the vector x passing through the plane created by endpoints of the 4 vectors?

Comment: @mike they are in R3

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Do you think that $a,b,c,d$ always line in the same plane???

Comment: Also, what is the "endpoint of a vector"? Never heard of such nonsense.

Comment: @Vladimir in my problem they are always in plane. You give me a solution for the the 3 in plane. please

Comment: i mean the x,y,z value of the vector.

Comment: @Vladimir ok just tell me how to check that a vector is intersecting a plane or not. the plane has borders formed by the points that makes the plane. so the vector may not intersect the plane and pass it nearly. help me now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $a,b,c$ do not lie on one line, consider the following system of three linear equations for three unknowns $y_1,y_2,y_3$: 
$$
 a+y_1(b-a)+y_2(c-a)=y_3x.
$$
If it is not solvable, then the segment $[0,x]$ is parallel to the plane. If it has infinitely many solutions, then the segment $[0,x]$ lies in the plane. If it has only one solution, then the segment $[0,x]$ intersects the plane if and only if $y_3\in[0,1]$ (or you might wish to check the condition $y_3\in(0,1)$ if you need that the intersection be at an interior point of the segment). If you need that the point of intersection lie inside the triangle formed by $a,b,c$ then you should additionally check that $y_1\ge0$, $y_2\ge0$, and $y_1+y_2\le 1$.